# Qt5.1 failed to load platform plugin xcb

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu

i’m using ubuntu 12.04 and qt5.1. i compile my project with no errors but when i try to launch my application on other machine i get the following error:

```
Failed to load platform plugin "xcb". Available platforms are:

Annullato (core dump creato)
```

i add the required libraries to the ld_library_path:

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7705000)
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /home/computer/libs/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0xb70c4000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /home/computer/libs/libQt5Core.so.5 (0xb6c42000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb6b5c000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb6b3e000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb6995000)
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => /home/computer/libs/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0xb652a000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /home/computer/libs/libpthread.so.0 (0xb650f000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /home/computer/libs/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0xb64bf000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /home/computer/libs/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0xb63c6000)
    libX11.so.6 => /home/computer/libs/libX11.so.6 (0xb6292000)
    libm.so.6 => /home/computer/libs/libm.so.6 (0xb6266000)
    libicui18n.so.51 => /home/computer/libs/libicui18n.so.51 (0xb6044000)
    libicuuc.so.51 => /home/computer/libs/libicuuc.so.51 (0xb5eca000)
    libdl.so.2 => /home/computer/libs/libdl.so.2 (0xb5ec5000)
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /home/computer/libs/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0xb5ec2000)
    librt.so.1 => /home/computer/libs/librt.so.1 (0xb5eb9000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7706000)
    libGL.so.1 => /home/computer/libs/libGL.so.1 (0xb5e5a000)
    libffi.so.6 => /home/computer/libs/libffi.so.6 (0xb5e52000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /home/computer/libs/libpcre.so.3 (0xb5e16000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /home/computer/libs/libxcb.so.1 (0xb5df5000)
    libicudata.so.51 => /home/computer/libs/libicudata.so.51 (0xb48ac000)
    libglapi.so.0 => /home/computer/libs/libglapi.so.0 (0xb4895000)
    libXext.so.6 => /home/computer/libs/libXext.so.6 (0xb4882000)
    libXdamage.so.1 => /home/computer/libs/libXdamage.so.1 (0xb487e000)
    libXfixes.so.3 => /home/computer/libs/libXfixes.so.3 (0xb4878000)
    libX11-xcb.so.1 => /home/computer/libs/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0xb4875000)
    libxcb-glx.so.0 => /home/computer/libs/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0xb485d000)
    libXxf86vm.so.1 => /home/computer/libs/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0xb4856000)
    libdrm.so.2 => /home/computer/libs/libdrm.so.2 (0xb4849000)
    libXau.so.6 => /home/computer/libs/libXau.so.6 (0xb4845000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /home/computer/libs/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xb483e000)
```

but it doesn’t work. what is the problem?

i also try to reconfigure qt with the option -qt-xcb but it still doesn’t work.

ps. sorry for my bad english

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Failed to load platform plugin "xcb" " while launching qt5 app on linux without qt installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106315/failed-to-load-platform-plugin-xcb-while-launching-qt5-app-on-linux-without)

Answer (score 19):

Please download this packages:

```
sudo apt-get install "^libxcb.*" libx11-xcb-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libxrender-dev
```

You can check why it don't work by using:

```
export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1
```

and make run your app in terminal

if it dosen't work try

```
locate libxcb.so.1
```

and write this path in

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/**MY_PATH**:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: Get +1 for `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1` environment variable, it made my day!