# Error on execution -version `Qt_5' not found required by

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, qt5.6

On execution of eiskaltdc++ on ubuntu 15.10 ,I get the following error:

```
eiskaltdcpp-qt: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Multimedia.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by eiskaltdcpp-qt)
eiskaltdcpp-qt: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by eiskaltdcpp-qt)
eiskaltdcpp-qt: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Concurrent.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by eiskaltdcpp-qt)
eiskaltdcpp-qt: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Sql.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by eiskaltdcpp-qt)
eiskaltdcpp-qt: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by eiskaltdcpp-qt)
eiskaltdcpp-qt: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Xml.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by eiskaltdcpp-qt)
eiskaltdcpp-qt: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.6' not found (required by eiskaltdcpp-qt)
eiskaltdcpp-qt: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by eiskaltdcpp-qt)
eiskaltdcpp-qt: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by eiskaltdcpp-qt)
```

## Qt version

```
~$ which qmake
/opt/Qt5.6.0/5.6/gcc_64/bin/qmake
~$ qmake -version
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.6.0 in /opt/Qt5.6.0/5.6/gcc_64/lib
~$ echo $PATH
/opt/Qt5.6.0/5.6/gcc_64/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

I am able to successfully compile applications with Qt creator.

## Edit

running ldd gave me this.I am not sure how to interpret this

```
~$ ldd /usr/local/bin/eiskaltdcpp-qt
/usr/local/bin/eiskaltdcpp-qt: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Multimedia.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by /usr/local/bin/eiskaltdcpp-qt)
/usr/local/bin/eiskaltdcpp-qt: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by /usr/local/bin/eiskaltdcpp-qt)
/usr/local/bin/eiskaltdcpp-qt: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Concurrent.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by /usr/local/bin/eiskaltdcpp-qt)
/usr/local/bin/eiskaltdcpp-qt: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Sql.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by /usr/local/bin/eiskaltdcpp-qt)
/usr/local/bin/eiskaltdcpp-qt: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by /usr/local/bin/eiskaltdcpp-qt)
/usr/local/bin/eiskaltdcpp-qt: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Xml.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by /usr/local/bin/eiskaltdcpp-qt)
/usr/local/bin/eiskaltdcpp-qt: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.6' not found (required by /usr/local/bin/eiskaltdcpp-qt)
/usr/local/bin/eiskaltdcpp-qt: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by /usr/local/bin/eiskaltdcpp-qt)
/usr/local/bin/eiskaltdcpp-qt: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by /usr/local/bin/eiskaltdcpp-qt)
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd580bf000)
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007fbeffcec000)
    libQt5Xml.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Xml.so.5 (0x00007fbeffcb0000)
    libQt5Multimedia.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Multimedia.so.5 (0x00007fbeffbcf000)
    libQt5Concurrent.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Concurrent.so.5 (0x00007fbeffbc8000)
    libQt5DBus.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so.5 (0x00007fbeffb47000)
    libQt5Sql.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Sql.so.5 (0x00007fbeffb04000)
    libboost_system.so.1.58.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.58.0 (0x00007fbeff900000)
    libeiskaltdcpp.so.2.3 => /usr/local/lib/libeiskaltdcpp.so.2.3 (0x00007fbeff52d000)
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007fbefeff2000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007fbefeb36000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fbefe918000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fbefe54d000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fbefe1cb000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fbefdec3000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fbefdcab000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fbefda58000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fbefd749000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007fbefd40e000)
    libQt5Network.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5 (0x00007fbefd2bb000)
    libpulse.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpulse.so.0 (0x00007fbefd06c000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fbefce63000)
    libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007fbefcc17000)
    libbz2.so.1.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0 (0x00007fbefca06000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fbefc7ec000)
    libssl.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007fbefc583000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007fbefc13e000)
    libpcrecpp.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcrecpp.so.0 (0x00007fbefbf34000)
    libattr.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libattr.so.1 (0x00007fbefbd2f000)
    libpng12.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0x00007fbefbb08000)
    libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007fbefb8aa000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/nvidia-352/libGL.so.1 (0x00007fbefb57a000)
    libicui18n.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.55 (0x00007fbefb116000)
    libicuuc.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55 (0x00007fbefad82000)
    libpcre16.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre16.so.3 (0x00007fbefab1f000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fbefa91a000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055b48dc4b000)
    libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007fbefa712000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007fbefa4a4000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007fbefa283000)
    libjson-c.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjson-c.so.2 (0x00007fbefa077000)
    libpulsecommon-6.0.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsecommon-6.0.so (0x00007fbef9dfe000)
    libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007fbef9d7d000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007fbef9ad6000)
    libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007fbef98b1000)
    libnvidia-tls.so.352.63 => /usr/lib/nvidia-352/tls/libnvidia-tls.so.352.63 (0x00007fbef96ad000)
    libnvidia-glcore.so.352.63 => /usr/lib/nvidia-352/libnvidia-glcore.so.352.63 (0x00007fbef6c1a000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007fbef6a08000)
    libicudata.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.55 (0x00007fbef4f50000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007fbef4d4c000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007fbef4b45000)
    libwrap.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwrap.so.0 (0x00007fbef493b000)
    libsndfile.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsndfile.so.1 (0x00007fbef46d2000)
    libasyncns.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasyncns.so.0 (0x00007fbef44cc000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007fbef42a9000)
    libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007fbef3fc7000)
    libnsl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007fbef3dac000)
    libFLAC.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libFLAC.so.8 (0x00007fbef3b37000)
    libvorbisenc.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbisenc.so.2 (0x00007fbef3884000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007fbef3668000)
    libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007fbef3455000)
    libogg.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0 (0x00007fbef324c000)
    libvorbis.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0 (0x00007fbef301f000)
```

Please suggest a solution.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not in LD_LIBRARY_PATH ?

Comment: @Benjamin What should be the value?

Comment: Try ldd eiskaltdcpp-qt and look for not found or missing in the list of libraries that should be in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Then there are various way to add them (look at ldconfig)

Comment: @Benjamin Could you please check the ldd results?.I dont see any other missing libraries.thanks

Comment: Nothing is missing. I have no more ideas. Sorry & good luck

Comment: try to run with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/Qt5.6.0/5.6/gcc_64/lib/`

Comment: @nib .Thanks  it worked.:)..Could you explain it as an answer?

Comment: according to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106315/failed-to-load-platform-plugin-xcb-while-launching-qt5-app-on-linux-without) you can `export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1` not sure if this will help, but it might give you some more information

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Issue happens because you have Qt installed in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` from distro which ld will use by default. To avoid such issues you can compile with `-rpath` or run with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/your/Qt/libs/location` to help linker find needed Qt version.

Comment: I did not understand what "run with LD_LIBRARY_PATH" meant, only through another thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50395911/qtcreator-qt-5-not-found/52422726#52422726). 

It means run in terminal "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ qtcreator" instead of just "qtcreator". That works for me, so thanks!

Comment: I am running on arm64.  I had to add /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu to LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: dear nib &  @gebbissimo  I have two locations , 1. my cross-compiled qt which is configured for aarch64, 2. my target machine rootfs, which location LD_LIBRARY_PATH should refer to?

Answer (score 9):

To update QT to 5.14 on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS x86_64:

- `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:beineri/opt-qt-5.14.0-bionic`
- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get install qt514-meta-minimal -y`
- `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/qt514/lib/`

More details: [https://launchpad.net/~beineri/+archive/ubuntu/opt-qt-5.14.0-bionic](https://launchpad.net/%7Ebeineri/+archive/ubuntu/opt-qt-5.14.0-bionic)

Answer (score 2):

Install Qt5.x.0 (what version you need) , find install path and copy all file `gcc_64/lib/*` into

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/*
```

Comment: Copying files which are not managed by the package manager into a directory managed by the package manager is generally a bad idea.

Comment: What worked for me is having `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/*` instead of `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` in my qMake file.

Answer (score -3):

The easiest way to fix this is installing the QT developer package:

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-default
```

This will install the packages you need.

Comment: This error happens even when the packages are installed. It means the packages are there, but of incompatible version.

Comment: Tried that and it told me "qt5-default is already the newest version (5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.1)." - the problem persists.

Comment: It looks like qt5-default is no longer available for Debian Unstable as of the date of this comment. I'm not sure if this is true for Ubuntu.