# Running QtQuick-App on Ubuntu Phone: Qt_5 not found

Tags: c++, qml, qt5

I created a new QtQuick-Application with the ubuntu-sdk. I builds and uploads fine to an attached Ubuntu-Phone (Aquaris E4.5, OS-Build OTA-14, 20161118), but it fails to start:

```
Installiert  quickie.micha-0.1.armhf (installed:click,removable=1,app_name=quickie)
Sdk-Launcher> Application installed successfully
Sdk-Launcher> AppId:                   quickie.micha_quickie_0.1
Sdk-Launcher> Architecture:            armhf
Sdk-Launcher> Application confined:    True
Sdk-Launcher> Communication directory: /home/phablet/.local/share/quickie.micha/
Sdk-Launcher> Not able to open syslog, apparmor errors will not be reported.
Sdk-Launcher> Application started: 17330
Debug-helper> Setting up environment
Debug-helper> TmpDir:      /home/phablet/.local/share/quickie.micha/
Debug-helper> AppId:       quickie.micha_quickie_0.1
Debug-helper> Environment: confined
Debug-helper> Environment initialized, starting the application
Debug-helper> Executing /opt/click.ubuntu.com/.click/users/phablet/quickie.micha/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/quickie['/opt/click.ubuntu.com/.click/users/phablet/quickie.micha/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/quickie']
/opt/click.ubuntu.com/.click/users/phablet/quickie.micha/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/quickie: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Qml.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by /opt/click.ubuntu.com/.click/users/phablet/quickie.micha/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/quickie)
/opt/click.ubuntu.com/.click/users/phablet/quickie.micha/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/quickie: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Quick.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by /opt/click.ubuntu.com/.click/users/phablet/quickie.micha/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/quickie)
/opt/click.ubuntu.com/.click/users/phablet/quickie.micha/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/quickie: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by /opt/click.ubuntu.com/.click/users/phablet/quickie.micha/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/quickie)
/opt/click.ubuntu.com/.click/users/phablet/quickie.micha/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/quickie: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Gui.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by /opt/click.ubuntu.com/.click/users/phablet/quickie.micha/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/quickie)
Sdk-Launcher> Received a failed event
Sdk-Launcher> The Application exited, cleaning up
Sdk-Launcher> Finished
```

Qt5 libraries seem to be installed on the device:

```
phablet@ubuntu-phablet:/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf$ find . -type f -name "libQt5*"
./libQt5Core.so.5.4.1
./libQt5Contacts.so.5.0.0
./libQt5DBus.so.5.4.1
./libQt5Feedback.so.5.0.0
./libQt5Gui.so.5.4.1
./libQt5Concurrent.so.5.4.1
./libQt5Qml.so.5.4.1
./libQt5Network.so.5.4.1
./libQt5OpenGL.so.5.4.1
./libQt5Quick.so.5.4.1
./libQt5QuickParticles.so.5.4.1
./libQt5QuickTest.so.5.4.1
./libQt5Location.so.5.4.1
./libQt5Sql.so.5.4.1
./libQt5Test.so.5.4.1
./libQt5Widgets.so.5.4.1
./libQt5Xml.so.5.4.1
./libQt5Multimedia.so.5.4.1
./libQt5MultimediaQuick_p.so.5.4.1
./libQt5MultimediaWidgets.so.5.4.1
./libQt5Organizer.so.5.0.0
./libQt5Positioning.so.5.4.1
./libQt5Sensors.so.5.4.1
./libQt5Versit.so.5.0.0
./libQt5VersitOrganizer.so.5.0.0
./libQt5Purchasing.so.5.6.0
./libQt5Svg.so.5.4.1
./libQt5XmlPatterns.so.5.4.1
./libQt5Script.so.5.4.1
./libQt5Bluetooth.so.5.4.1
./libQt5SystemInfo.so.5.4.0
./libQt5WebSockets.so.5.4.1
```

I wonder, which binary is executed, because

```
/opt/click.ubuntu.com/.click/users/phablet/quickie.micha/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/quickie
```

does not exist on the device.

Are there any working examples using the ubuntu-sdk, qml & c++ and a physical device?

The tutorial *Add a C++ backend to your QML UI* shows the same missing *Qt_5 not found* problem, but I understand, that that is a desktop example.

I have built the pure-qml/js CurrencyConverter-App and that works absolutely fine.

Any help is appreciated. Many thanks in advance and kind regards, Michael.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error on execution -version \`Qt\_5' not found required by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36128645/error-on-execution-version-qt-5-not-found-required-by)

Comment: Yes I have read that post. But it does not deal with the ubuntu-phone as the target-platform.

Comment: May be you have different version on the phone from that you have compiled with? ie 5.2 and 5.7? Or may be your application was compiled in debug mode. just a guess.

Comment: ah, solved it: I was using the wrong kit: my phone runs on ubuntu 15.04, the project in ubuntu-sdk was set for armhf-ubuntu-sdk-16.04.

Comment: folibis, thanks a lot. Your suggestion to check the versions was absolutely right.