# Why am I unable to Launch sqlite browser in ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: sqlite

I have downloaded DB sqlite browser by following the instructions on the official [site](http://sqlitebrowser.org) of db browser sqlite.

I've followed the instructions in the order mentioned on the website.

This is what I typed in terminal to launch the software:

```
sdm@sdm-Inspiron-13-5368:~$ sqlitebrowser 
sqlitebrowser: /usr/local/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.9' not found (required by sqlitebrowser)
sqlitebrowser: /usr/local/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5)
sqlitebrowser: /usr/local/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Xml.so.5)
```

Why am I unable to launch it? What should I do launch it?

Comment: [Error on execution -version `Qt_5' not found required by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36128645/error-on-execution-version-qt-5-not-found-required-by)

Comment: I did sdm@sdm-Inspiron-13-5368:~$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtcreator and tried to launch it but still getting the same error.