# /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.12' not found

Tags: qt, makefile, cmake, windows-subsystem-for-linux, .so

**Problem :**

I am installing QT 5.12 on Windows Subsystem for Linux using [these instructions](https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git#Getting_the_source_code). I am facing a problem with the QT library file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version`Qt_5.12'`not being found during`make -j4`.

**Things I tried before posting this question :**

- [Discussion 1](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/2606)
- [Discussion 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36128645/error-on-execution-version-qt-5-not-found-required-by)
- [Discussion 3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034313/ubuntu-18-4-libqt5core-so-5-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-dir)
- [Discussion 4](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/wiki/Fix-error-while-loading-shared-libraries:-libQt5Core.so.5)
- [Discussion 5](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/70315-libQt5Core-so-5-version-Qt_5-12-not-found-error)
- [Discussion 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428910/how-to-set-the-environmental-variable-ld-library-path-in-linux)

None of these solutions worked.

I also verified with `find` command on Ubuntu to see whether the library exists :

```
arun@DESKTOP-TG2ATQ1:/usr$ find -iname libQt5Core.so.5
./lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
```

**The detailed error report is attached below :**

```
   arun@DESKTOP-TG2ATQ1:/mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard$ make -j1                                                                
   cd qtbase/ && ( test -e Makefile || /mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase/bin/qmake -o Makefile 
   /mnt/f/QT_Source/qt5/qtbase/qtbase.pro ) && make -f Makefile                                                                                         
   make[1]: Entering directory '/mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase'                                                                
   cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile || /mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase/bin/qmake -o Makefile    
   /mnt/f/QT_Source/qt5/qtbase/src/src.pro ) && make -f Makefile                                                                                           
   make[2]: Entering directory '/mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase/src'                                                      
   cd tools/bootstrap/ && ( test -e Makefile || /mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase/bin/qmake -o Makefile 
   /mnt/f/QT_Source/qt5/qtbase/src/tools/bootstrap/bootstrap.pro ) && make -f Makefile                                                         
   make[3]: Entering directory '/mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase/src/tools/bootstrap'                                      
   make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'first'.                                                                                
   make[3]: Leaving directory '/mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase/src/tools/bootstrap'                                       
   cd tools/moc/ && ( test -e Makefile || /mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase/bin/qmake -o Makefile 
   /mnt/f/QT_Source/qt5/qtbase/src/tools/moc/moc.pro ) && make -f Makefile                                                                           
   make[3]: Entering directory '/mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase/src/tools/moc'                                            
   make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'first'.                                                                                
   make[3]: Leaving directory '/mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase/src/tools/moc'                                             
   cd tools/rcc/ && ( test -e Makefile || /mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase/bin/qmake -o Makefile 
   /mnt/f/QT_Source/qt5/qtbase/src/tools/rcc/rcc.pro ) && make -f Makefile                                                                           
   make[3]: Entering directory '/mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase/src/tools/rcc'                                            
   make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'first'.                                                                                
   make[3]: Leaving directory '/mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase/src/tools/rcc'                                             
   cd tools/qfloat16-tables/ && ( test -e Makefile || /mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase/bin/qmake -o 
   Makefile /mnt/f/QT_Source/qt5/qtbase/src/tools/qfloat16-tables/qfloat16-tables.pro ) && make -f 
   Makefile                                       make[3]: Entering directory 
   '/mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase/src/tools/qfloat16-tables'                                make[3]: 
   Nothing to be done for 'first'.                                                                                
   make[3]: Leaving directory '/mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase/src/tools/qfloat16-tables'                                 
   cd 3rdparty/pcre2/ && ( test -e Makefile || /mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase/bin/qmake -o Makefile 
   /mnt/f/QT_Source/qt5/qtbase/src/3rdparty/pcre2/pcre2.pro ) && make -f Makefile                                                               
   make[3]: Entering directory '/mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase/src/3rdparty/pcre2'                                       
   make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'first'.                                                                                
   make[3]: Leaving directory '/mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase/src/3rdparty/pcre2'                                        
   cd corelib/ && ( test -e Makefile || /mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase/bin/qmake -o Makefile 
   /mnt/f/QT_Source/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/corelib.pro ) && make -f Makefile                                                                           
   make[3]: Entering directory '/mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase/src/corelib'                                              
   make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'first'.                                                                                
   make[3]: Leaving directory '/mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase/src/corelib'                                               
   cd tools/qlalr/ && ( test -e Makefile || /mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase/bin/qmake -o Makefile 
   /mnt/f/QT_Source/qt5/qtbase/src/tools/qlalr/qlalr.pro ) && make -f Makefile                                                                     
   make[3]: Entering directory '/mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase/src/tools/qlalr'                                          
   make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'first'.                                                                                
   make[3]: Leaving directory '/mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase/src/tools/qlalr'                                           
   cd network/ && ( test -e Makefile || /mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase/bin/qmake -o Makefile 
   /mnt/f/QT_Source/qt5/qtbase/src/network/network.pro ) && make -f Makefile                                                                           
   make[3]: Entering directory '/mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase/src/network'                                              
   make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'first'.                                                                                
   make[3]: Leaving directory '/mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase/src/network'                                               
   cd sql/ && ( test -e Makefile || /mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase/bin/qmake -o Makefile 
   /mnt/f/QT_Source/qt5/qtbase/src/sql/sql.pro ) && make -f Makefile                                                                                       
   make[3]: Entering directory '/mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase/src/sql'                                                  
   make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'first'.                                                                                
   make[3]: Leaving directory '/mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase/src/sql'                                                   
   cd xml/ && ( test -e Makefile || /mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase/bin/qmake -o Makefile 
   /mnt/f/QT_Source/qt5/qtbase/src/xml/xml.pro ) && make -f Makefile                                                                                       
   make[3]: Entering directory '/mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase/src/xml'                                                  
   make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'first'.                                                                                
   make[3]: Leaving directory '/mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase/src/xml'                                                   
   cd tools/qvkgen/ && ( test -e Makefile || /mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase/bin/qmake -o Makefile 
   /mnt/f/QT_Source/qt5/qtbase/src/tools/qvkgen/qvkgen.pro ) && make -f Makefile                                                                  
   make[3]: Entering directory '/mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase/src/tools/qvkgen'                                         
   make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'first'.                                                                                
   make[3]: Leaving directory '/mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase/src/tools/qvkgen'                                          
   cd gui/ && ( test -e Makefile || /mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase/bin/qmake -o Makefile 
   /mnt/f/QT_Source/qt5/qtbase/src/gui/gui.pro ) && make -f Makefile                                                                                       
   make[3]: Entering directory '/mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase/src/gui'                                                  
   /mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase/src/gui/qvkgen_wrapper.sh 
   /mnt/f/QT_Source/qt5/qtbase/src/gui/vulkan/vk.xml /mnt/f/QT_Source/qt5/qtbase/header.LGPL 
   vulkan/qvulkanfunctions                                                                    
   /mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase/bin/qvkgen: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version 
   `Qt_5.12' not found (required by /mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase/bin/qvkgen)                                                                   
   Makefile:2028: recipe for target 'vulkan/qvulkanfunctions.h' failed                                                     
   make[3]: *** [vulkan/qvulkanfunctions.h] Error 1                                                                        
   make[3]: Leaving directory '/mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase/src/gui'                                                   
   Makefile:502: recipe for target 'sub-gui-make_first' failed                                                             
   make[2]: *** [sub-gui-make_first] Error 2                                                                               
   make[2]: Leaving directory '/mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase/src'                                                       
   Makefile:50: recipe for target 'sub-src-make_first' failed                                                              
   make[1]: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2                                                                               
   make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/f/QT_Source/junkyard/qtbase'                                                           
   Makefile:86: recipe for target 'module-qtbase-make_first' failed                                                        
   make: *** [module-qtbase-make_first] Error 2
```

Comment: Why is this question tagged `cmake`?

Comment: "I am installing QT 5.12 on Windows Subsystem for Linux" suggests that the problem is about installing Qt, but the error messages seem to pertain to building other software *after* installing Qt.  Please clarify.

Comment: In any case, a build problem such as this depends on a lot of details not currently presented.  How did you build and install Qt (or how are you attempting to do so)? How did you configure the build for the software you are presently trying to build?

Comment: Also, the error message suggests that you already *have* Qt, but of an older version.  This will have come with the OS.  Do you really need version 5.12, then?