# cannot find qt platform plugin xcb

Tags: qt, virtual-machine, virtualbox

i was trying to install VirtualBox to use OS X on my LUBUNTU computer.
After I installed it, i tried to run it but it didn't due to this error:

```
    Qt FATAL: This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin"xcb".
    Aviable platform plugins are: xcb. Reinstalling the application may fix the problem.
```

I'm here to ask you to help me with this. I already tried to reinstall the application but nothing worked. Any ideas? Please by clear, i'm just a beginner so I have difficulties, expecially using terminal.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Failed to load platform plugin "xcb" " while launching qt5 app on linux without qt installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106315/failed-to-load-platform-plugin-xcb-while-launching-qt5-app-on-linux-without)

Answer (score 4):

For me It was the xlibxcb-xinerama on fresh install ubuntu 18.04.1

```
apt-get install --reinstall libxcb-xinerama0
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because of missing dependencies for the XCB plugin. To solve it, find the libqxcb.so file (inside plugins/platforms or somewhere else) and run ldd on it.

ldd will display all dependencies and you will have to install packages corresponding to the NOT FOUND entries.

After that the application should work.