# Qt linking error when running OpenCV python application in Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, opencv, conda

I am running 4.1.0 with python 3.7.3. I installed opencv using conda:

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

I don't have any experience using Qt. I am simply trying to show an image or a video using the OpenCV `imshow` method:

```py
cv.imshow('Result (Press any key to exit)', img)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

But when I run the program, I get this error:

```
xkbcommon: ERROR: failed to add default include path 
Qt: Failed to create XKB context!
Use QT_XKB_CONFIG_ROOT environmental variable to provide an additional search path, add ':' as separator to provide several search paths and/or make sure that XKB configuration data directory contains recent enough contents, to update please see http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xkeyboard-config/ .
```

The program continues to run just fine. However cv.waitKey(0) is not working. I read up about setting the environment variable, but I plan to bundle this program using pyinstaller, so I can't rely on this fix forever.

Is there a permanent fix?

Comment: How have you installed opencv?

Comment: through anaconda: `conda install -c conda-forge opencv` I am running 4.1.0 with python 3.7.3

Comment: This information is important, edit your question and add it there.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42595685/this-application-failed-to-start-because-it-could-not-find-or-load-the-qt-platfo and https://github.com/conda-forge/qt-feedstock/issues/104

Comment: `conda update -c conda-forge qt` did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is referenced here: https://github.com/conda-forge/qt-feedstock/issues/104. Fixes have been merged into master.

For Ubuntu, you can update Qt to fix this issue:

> conda install -c conda-forge qt

`qt  5.9.7-h52cfd70_1 --> 5.9.7-h52cfd70_2`