# Deployement Qt error

Tags: linux, qt, deployment

I try to deploy a simple hello world GUI on Qt on linux
I first compile the program on QTcreator and I collect all the needed library with that shell script:
https://h3manth.com/content/copying-shared-library-dependencies

Then I get that error:

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"
in "".
```

I found on stackoverflow ["Failed to load platform plugin "xcb" " while launching qt5 app on linux without qt installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106315/failed-to-load-platform-plugin-xcb-while-launching-qt5-app-on-linux-without)
that the trouble should come from a lack of library.

So I take all the so file in my /Qt/5.7/gcc_64 and I put all these on my other computer.
I do a export LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the folder where the library are located but I still get that error.

```
 This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"
in "".
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106315/failed-to-load-platform-plugin-xcb-while-launching-qt5-app-on-linux-without

Comment: It is not the same. It is because I made all what is advice in that post but it still stuck.

Comment: There is a Folder with Qt source called plugins. Include this folder with your exe and see if it works. If i doesn't work, add the path using `void QCoreApplication::addLibraryPath(const QString &path)`