# Using static linked QT build with QtCreator on Linux

Tags: linux, qt, qt-creator, qmake, xcb

I'm trying to build my application with static linking, in one file. I connected a new Qt prefix into QtCreator. Application is builds, but when i trying to launch it, i got

> This application failed to start because it could not find or load the
>   Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "". Reinstalling the application may fix
>   this problem.

Configure

```
./configure -static -release -qt-xcb -opensource -confirm-license -
skip multimedia -no-compile-examples -nomake examples -no-openssl -
skip wayland -prefix /home/brainrom/qt_static
```

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Can't you try searching this site at least? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106315/failed-to-load-platform-plugin-xcb-while-launching-qt5-app-on-linux-without

Comment: But i want to build my application with static linking in single file. Without application folder. Maybe i can link dependcies static too?