# Qt5 libraries mistakenly deleted

Tags: linux, ubuntu, qt5, ldd, cmake-gui

I mistakenly deleted all qt5 related files in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu. So, I installed qt5 again using

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-default
sudo apt-get install qtdeclarative5-dev
```

But, applications that use qt5 complains that somethings are missing.
For example,

```
$ qtcreator
qtcreator: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Test.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

$ qtpaths 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qtpaths: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.6' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qtpaths)
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qtpaths: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qtpaths)

$ cmake-gui
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb".
```

How do I correctly reinstall qt5 and make these applications working?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: try with: `sudo apt-get install libqt5test5`

Comment: So I installed lots of libqt5*5's and at the end running qt5 related application gives me

[code] This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"
in "".
Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, mirserver, ubuntumirclient, xcb. [code]

Comment: read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106315/failed-to-load-platform-plugin-xcb-while-launching-qt5-app-on-linux-without

Comment: Aha! Now it seems to be working! Thank you so much

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Failed to load platform plugin "xcb" " while launching qt5 app on linux without qt installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106315/failed-to-load-platform-plugin-xcb-while-launching-qt5-app-on-linux-without)

Comment: come on, it's a subset of this problem...

Comment: But after all, they both have the same error message, it's the same problem, you went through the solution that's the good thing, but for a next opportunity, do a little search before posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

Xcb support is part of Qt X11 stuff. Try install "Qt 5 X11 extras" (libqt5x11extras5-dev). 
Another solution that will hard but works to make own Qt build from sources.