# libGL.so.1 not found: Qt GUI app in docker with centos

Tags: qt, docker, centos

I am trying to run a Qt app in docker. I have a very limited Linux experience. The OS is centos. Qt version is 5.9.1. The overall idea is to run it in Xvbf. (*I have already run firefox in DISPLAY:1(Xvbf) inside docker under centos*)

When I try "docker run -it myTestGuiApp", I get an error libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

What is missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a missing library. You might need to install this : `yum install mesa-libGL`

Just add this line in your dockerfile : `RUN yum install mesa-libGL`

If this doesn't work, copy here your dockerfile.

Comment: Thanks Wassim;  installing mesa-libGL solves this problem. But Now I am getting: This application failed to start because it could not find or load Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "". Available platform plugins are :xcb. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem. Any insight?

Comment: According to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106315/failed-to-load-platform-plugin-xcb-while-launching-qt5-app-on-linux-without You are still missing some libraries, some things related to X11 I think. Try getting inside your container using `docker exec -it CONTAINER_NAME bash` and then doing a `ldd libqxcb.so` to check missing liibraries

Comment: Thanks, Now I can run it properly.

Comment: How did you fix it eventually?