# Importing matplotlib with reticulate in R

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, reticulate

I just started using the reticulate package in R, and I'm still getting a few of the kinks figured out. In particular, importing matplotlib is not going well. I've tried it two different ways, with different error messages for each.

First, using repl_python in RStudio's interactive shell:

```
library(reticulate)
use_python('/home/craig/anaconda3/bin/python')
py_discover_config()
repl_python()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

The REPL Python shell that opens up seems to have the correct version and everything, but when I try to import matplotlib.pyplot, I see the following:

ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.9' not found (required by /home/craig/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/../../.././libpng16.so.16)

Installing zlib (using `sudo apt-get install lib64z1-dev lib64z1`) didn't seem to change anything. FWIW, `import matplotlib` worked just fine, as long as I don't need `pyplot`.

I also tried doing the same thing in an R Markdown document:

````
```{r}
library(reticulate)
py_discover_config()
```

```{python}
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```
````

This time I saw:

Error in py_get_attr_impl(x, name, silent): AtributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'pyplot' Calls:  ... $.python.builtin.object -> py_get_attr -> py_get_attr_impl -> .Call Execution halted

Any ideas what might be going on here?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** As I mentioned in the comments, installing the developer version of reticulate fixes some of the problems, but not all. If I try to run this Rmd:

````
```{r}
library(reticulate)
use_python('/home/craig/anaconda3/bin/python')
```

```{python}
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```
````

I get the following error messages:

```
Error in py_run_string_impl(code, local, convert) : 
  ImportError: /home/craig/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/../../../libxcb-dri3.so.0: undefined symbol: xcb_send_request_with_fds

Detailed traceback: 
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/craig/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 116, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "/home/craig/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 60, in pylab_setup
[backend_name], 0)
  File "/home/craig/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5agg.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .backend_qt5 import (
  File "/home/craig/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py", line 18, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backends.qt_editor.figureoptions as figureoptions
  File "/home/craig/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/qt_editor/figureoptions.py", line 20, in <module>
Calls: <Anonymous> ... force -> py_run_string -> py_run_string_impl -> .Call
Execution halted
```

When I tried googling the error text, a [similar error with xcb](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/5249) does seem to be coming up in a context that is, as far as I can tell, not so relevant.

Comment: in your r markdown example you import matplotlib but not matplotlib.pyplot. is that just a copy and paste error?

Comment: It is, but I actually get the same error even if I just import `matplotlib` rather than `matplotlib.pyplot`. Importing `matplotlib` sans pyplot using` `repl_python()` rather than R Markdown gives no error.

Comment: UPDATE: The R Markdown problem is still there, but I was able to solve the `repl_python()` error by following the instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48306849/lib-x86-64-linux-gnu-libz-so-1-version-zlib-1-2-9-not-found

Comment: UPDATE 2: Installing the developer version of reticulate using `devtools::install_github("rstudio/reticulate")` helps a little (i.e. I can now `import matplotlib` without an error), but I'm still getting errors when I try to `import matplotlib.pyplot`.

Comment: Getting the same error. Not getting the error if I just import matplotlib but as soon as I reference maltplotlib.pyplot it errors out. This was just in R console in RStudio as opposed to RMarkdown fwiw.

Comment: This link helped fix my problem as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48306849/lib-x86-64-linux-gnu-libz-so-1-version-zlib-1-2-9-not-found

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get things working by changing the R Markdown code block to read:

````
```{r}
library(reticulate)
use_python('/usr/bin/python3')
```

```{python}
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```
````

I still don't really understand why, but it seems that `reticulate` doesn't play nice with anaconda installations. Maybe it has something to do with anaconda being set up to work well with an interactive Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work with my conda install by sym linking the conda lib file to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/.

`ln -s -f /opt/miniconda/lib/libz.so.1 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1`

I noticed that if I ran python alone with the same import it worked fine. It appears that reticulate isn't 'seeing' the conda lib as a source for libz but does look in the `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` directory.

Python: 3.6
Conda: 4.5.1
OS: Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Comment: Same problem -- tried this and it had very negative consequences, effectively killing my EC2 instance

Answer (score 0):

I found the same error with reticulate, which is not reading the zlib from the anaconda library but from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/.

Instead of symlinking, I just run the following line from terminal each time I'm using the script:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/craig/anaconda3/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

You can actually run it from inside the R script, giving:

```
system('export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/craig/anaconda3/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been working with reticulate and R Markdown and you should specify your virtual environment.  For example my R Markdown starts as follows:

```
{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, warning = FALSE, cache.lazy = FALSE)
library(reticulate)

use_condaenv('pytorch')
```

Then you can work in either language. So, for plotting with matplotlib, I have found that you need the PyQt5 module to make it all run smoothly. The following makes a nice plot inside R Markdown.

```
{python plot}
import PyQt5
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure

data = pd.read_csv('Subscriptions.csv',index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)

# make the nice plot
# set the figure size
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (15,10))

# the series
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax1.plot(data.index.values, data.Opens, color = 'green', label = 'Opens')

# plot the legend for the first plot
ax1.legend(loc = 'upper right', fontsize = 14)

plt.ylabel('Opens', fontsize=16)

# Hide the top x axis
ax1.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)

#######  NOW PLOT THE OTHER SERIES ON A SINGLE PLOT

# plot 212 is the MI series

# plot series
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
ax2.plot(data.index.values, data.Joiners, color = 'orange', label = 'Joiners')

# plot the legend for the second plot
ax2.legend(loc = 'upper right', fontsize = 14)

# set the fontsize for the bottom plot
plt.ylabel('Joiners', fontsize=16)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]