# Pepper robot emulator is not starting

Tags: android, virtualization, pepper

I went through Getting Started guide on the SoftBank Robotics website (https://qisdk.softbankrobotics.com/sdk/doc/pepper-sdk/ch1_gettingstarted/installation.html), but I got blocked at the section "Running an application" where I had to start the Robot Pepper emulator. I press the icon, but there are no subsequent actions. 
In the event log I can see:
[Android Studio event log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTAgk.png)

There are no further logs. Is there a possibility to debug this process? Does Pepper Emulator store logs somewhere? How to investigate this issue further?

I have suspicions that I have virtualization issues on my computer. Yet normal Android emulator works and I have virtualization enabled in BIOS.

**EDIT_1**:
I found the logs. They are stored in `C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\Softbank Robotics\RobotSDK\Logs`, yet I couldn't find anything that could help me in my investigations.
Here is the snippet from the bottom part of the logs:

```
2020-01-03 00:40:13 INFO  Console:207 - Found attribute: minSdkVersion with value: API 6
2020-01-03 00:40:20 INFO  Console:207 - QI_WRITABLE_PATH=C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Roaming/Softbank Robotics/RobotSDK\API 6/naoqi-config/

"C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Roaming/Softbank Robotics/RobotSDK\API 6\tools/bin/naoqi-bin.exe" --qi-listen-url tcp://127.0.0.1:9570
2020-01-03 00:40:21 INFO  Console:207 - Found attribute: minSdkVersion with value: API 6
2020-01-03 00:40:21 INFO  Console:207 - PATH=C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/emulator;C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/emulator/lib64;C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/lib;C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/emulator/lib;C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/emulator/lib/qt/lib;

C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/emulator/qemu/windows-x86_64/qemu-system-i386.exe -sysdir "C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Roaming/Softbank Robotics/RobotSDK\API 6\avd/x86" -kernel "C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Roaming/Softbank Robotics/RobotSDK\API 6\avd/x86\kernel-ranchu" -system "C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Roaming/Softbank Robotics/RobotSDK\API 6\avd/x86\system.img" -ramdisk "C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Roaming/Softbank Robotics/RobotSDK\API 6\avd/x86\ramdisk.img" -data "C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Roaming/Softbank Robotics/RobotSDK\API 6\avd/x86\userdata.img" -cache "C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Roaming/Softbank Robotics/RobotSDK\API 6\avd/x86\cache.img" -skin 1280x800 -ports "5575, 5579" -sdcard "C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Roaming/Softbank Robotics/RobotSDK\API 6\avd/x86\sd-card.img" -gpu swiftshader_indirect -version
2020-01-03 00:40:22 INFO  Console:207 - NAOQI_BIN : [I] 1578008422.101513 30748 core.main: ..::: starting NAOqi version 2.9 :::..
2020-01-03 00:40:22 INFO  Console:207 - NAOQI_BIN : [I] 1578008422.101513 30748 core.main: Copyright (c) 2005-2019, SoftBank Robotics Europe
2020-01-03 00:40:22 INFO  Console:207 - NAOQI_BIN : [I] 1578008422.101513 30748 core.main: Build tag: naoqi-jenkins-release-2.9_ide-tools_win64-vs2015-311
2020-01-03 00:40:22 INFO  Console:207 - NAOQI_BIN : [I] 1578008422.329903 30748 packagemanager: Installing system packages
2020-01-03 00:40:22 INFO  Console:207 - NAOQI_BIN : [I] 1578008422.329903 30748 packagemanager: Looks for system package in C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\Softbank Robotics\RobotSDK\API 6\naoqi-config\data\naoqi\apps
2020-01-03 00:40:22 INFO  Console:207 - NAOQI_BIN : [I] 1578008422.330901 30748 packagemanager: Looks for system package in C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\Softbank Robotics\RobotSDK\API 6\tools\share\naoqi\apps
2020-01-03 00:40:23 INFO  Console:207 - PATH=C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/emulator;C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/emulator/lib64;C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/lib;C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/emulator/lib;C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/emulator/lib/qt/lib;

C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/emulator/qemu/windows-x86_64/qemu-system-i386.exe -sysdir "C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Roaming/Softbank Robotics/RobotSDK\API 6\avd/x86" -kernel "C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Roaming/Softbank Robotics/RobotSDK\API 6\avd/x86\kernel-ranchu" -system "C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Roaming/Softbank Robotics/RobotSDK\API 6\avd/x86\system.img" -ramdisk "C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Roaming/Softbank Robotics/RobotSDK\API 6\avd/x86\ramdisk.img" -data "C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Roaming/Softbank Robotics/RobotSDK\API 6\avd/x86\userdata.img" -cache "C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Roaming/Softbank Robotics/RobotSDK\API 6\avd/x86\cache.img" -skin 1280x800 -ports "5575, 5579" -sdcard "C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Roaming/Softbank Robotics/RobotSDK\API 6\avd/x86\sd-card.img" -gpu swiftshader_indirect -vendor none
2020-01-03 00:40:24 INFO  Console:207 - Closing emulator
2020-01-03 00:40:24 INFO  Console:207 - Process 'TABLET' is already killed
2020-01-03 00:40:24 INFO  Console:207 - Killing process : ROBOT_VIEWER_EMULATOR
2020-01-03 00:40:24 INFO  Console:207 - Connecting: tcp://127.0.0.1:9559
2020-01-03 00:40:27 INFO  Console:207 - Local Session state : ERROR
2020-01-03 00:40:27 INFO  Console:207 - Killing process tree : NAOQI_BIN
2020-01-03 00:40:37 INFO  ComponentStoreImpl:71 - Saving appFileTypeManager took 13 ms
2020-01-03 00:40:37 INFO  StoreUtil:71 - saveProjectsAndApp took 503 ms
```

Comment: This SDK is very anew, so few people got knowledge in this, so consider contacting softbank support.

Answer (score 1):

It's a Known issue: AVD does not work on Windows 10 with emulator 29.2.1 or higher

Workaround: Downgrade Android studio emulator to version 29.0.11

Download archive https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows-5598178.zip Go to repository C:\Users\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ Replace emulator folder by the emulator in the archive

Link: https://qisdk.softbankrobotics.com/sdk/doc/pepper-sdk/ch5_news/known_issues.html

Answer (score 0):

since the attached log doesn't show the error, I would recommend you enable virtualization on your machine and disable hypervision in windows

Comment: I have virtualization enabled and hyper-v turned off. I did everything that was described in "Gettin started" guide.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue, did you succeed to start the robot emulator ?

The only workaround for now is to start naoqi-bin.exe from the API directory then through the robor browser connect to the emulated robot but I can't connect to its tablet

Comment: How to start naoqi-bin.exe from the API directory?

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues and a sort of workaround:

**TL;DR: Try Ubuntu/Linux**

I tried to install the SDK on 3 different Windows PCs, I tried using different API versions and I even tried an older version of the Android Studio Pepper SDK plugin, none of which helped. The setup was never a problem. It is possible to create a virtual device through the Android Studio AVD Manager, since appearently the Pepper SDK plugin adds the appropriate device to the list of tablets. So you can test the UI, but not the Robot interactions.

The Pepper emulator simply didn't start at all. Since it is possible to start the "normal" Android Studio Emulator and also to start the naoqi-bin.exe and connect to the robot emulator as [Matthieu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59963421/6311832) described, everything should be working. I guess there is a problem in how the plugin tries to call the executables, or something on my machines interferes with the tools.

In the Android Studio Settings, you will find under Tools an option "Pepper Plugin Settings"

[image]

Here you can enable the Debug information which will be displayed in the Event Log. Still, this didn't help me. It showed something like

"Starting Emulator" and then the actual call to the executable, but nothing ever happened after that, so I guess the naoqi-bin.exe or something else in the chain must have crashed silently, without leaving a trace in the Event Log or in the SDKs log that you already found.

**In the end I installed Ubuntu** on my machine and got it working there. Again a few hickups since the virtualization must be configured in part manually, but the debug information from the plugin and Google helped me to quickly correct all wrongs. ([be carefull about the zlib.1.2.9 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50097275/6311832)!)