# ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory while importing OCC

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, anaconda, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, pythonocc

I have a Django application which it's deployed to `Amazon Elastic Beanstalk(Python 3.7 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.0.3)`. I have installed `anaconda` and `pythonocc-core` package by creating a `10_anaconda.config` file in `.ebextensions` folder.

10_anaconda.config;

```
commands:
  00_download_conda:
    command: 'wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2020.02-Linux-x86_64.sh'
  01_install_conda:
    command: 'bash Anaconda3-2020.02-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /anaconda'
  02_conda_install_pythonocc: 
    command: '/anaconda/bin/conda install -y -c dlr-sc pythonocc-core=7.4.0'
```

Then I have created a folder in one of my apps and created a `__init__.py` and `cadLoader.py` file into that folder.
I have added the anaconda path to `__init__.py` which it's in the `cad` folder;

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages')
```

And I have added the import lines to `cadLoader.py` for trying;

```
import os
from OCC.Extend.DataExchange import read_stl_file
from OCC.Display.SimpleGui import init_display
from OCC.Core.GProp import GProp_GProps
from OCC.Extend.DataExchange import read_step_file
from OCC.Extend.DataExchange import read_iges_file
from OCC.Core.Bnd import Bnd_Box
from OCC.Core.BRepMesh import BRepMesh_IncrementalMesh
from OCC.Core.BRepBndLib import brepbndlib_Add
from OCC.Core.BRepGProp import brepgprop_VolumeProperties
```

When I deployed it to Elastic Beanstalk, I got the error lines below.

```
from data.modellib.cad.cadLoader import CADLoader
File "/var/app/current/data/modellib/cad/cadLoader.py", line 2, in <module>
from OCC.Extend.DataExchange import read_stl_file
File "/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OCC/Extend/DataExchange.py", line 32, in <module>
from OCC.Core.XCAFDoc import (XCAFDoc_DocumentTool_ShapeTool,
File "/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OCC/Core/XCAFDoc.py", line 18, in <module>
from . import _XCAFDoc
ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

According to this issue, I have added a .config file for installing `libGL` such as below:

```
packages:
  yum:
    mesa-libGL : []
    mesa-libGL-devel : []
```

And in order to solve the `version ZLIB_1.2.9 not found` error, I added a config file like the one below.

```
commands:
    00_download_zlib:
        command: 'wget https://github.com/madler/zlib/archive/v1.2.9.tar.gz'
    01_open_zlib:
        command: 'tar xzvf v1.2.9.tar.gz'
    02_into_zlib:
        command: 'cd zlib-1.2.9'
    03_make_zlib:
        command: 'make'
    04_make_install_zlib:
        command: 'make install'
    05_libz_so:
        command: 'ln -fs /usr/local/lib/libz.so.1.2.9 /lib64/libz.so'
    06_libz_so_1:
        command: 'ln -fs /usr/local/lib/libz.so.1.2.9 /lib64/libz.so.1'
```

But my deployment is failed because of the `make` command. Here is my error message:

```
Unhandled exception during build: Command 03_make_zlib failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init", line 171, in <module>
    worklog.build(metadata, configSets)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 129, in build
    Contractor(metadata).build(configSets, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 530, in build
    self.run_config(config, worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 542, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 260, in build
    changes['commands'] = CommandTool().apply(self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 117, in apply
    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
ToolError: Command 03_make_zlib failed
```

How can I fix this issue and use the OCC package in my application?

Comment: You have to satisfy the dependency on libGL with your system's package manager. For ubuntu you would e.g. need to do `sudo apt-get install libgl1`. Probably you can find a reverse package search for your distribution [(e.g. this for ubuntu)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=eoan&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libGL.so.1&searchon=contents)

Comment: I installed the `mesa-libGL` and `mesa-libGL-devel`. the deployment was successfull but when I try to access the website, I'm getting `/lib64/libz.so.1: version ZLIB_1.2.9 not found (required by /anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OCC/Core/../../../../././././libpng16.so.16)` error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> /lib64/libz.so.1: version ZLIB_1.2.9 not found

**Amazon Linux 2** provides version 1.2.7:

```
Name        : zlib
Arch        : i686
Version     : 1.2.7
Release     : 18.amzn2
Size        : 91 k
Repo        : amzn2-core/2/x86_64
Summary     : The compression and decompression library
URL         : http://www.zlib.net/
License     : zlib and Boost
Description : Zlib is a general-purpose, patent-free, lossless data compression
            : library which is used by many different programs.
```

You can try manually upgrading the zlib to 1.2.9, for example performing the following steps as root (if they work, you can automated this through `.ebextentions`):

```
wget https://github.com/madler/zlib/archive/v1.2.9.tar.gz
tar xzvf v1.2.9.tar.gz
cd zlib-1.2.9
./configure
make
make install

ln -fs /usr/local/lib/libz.so.1.2.9 /lib64/libz.so
ln -fs /usr/local/lib/libz.so.1.2.9 /lib64/libz.so.1
```

This have to be carefully tested, as manual upgrades can break things. Some other options for upgrades are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48306849/lib-x86-64-linux-gnu-libz-so-1-version-zlib-1-2-9-not-found).

#### New config file

```
commands:
    00_download_zlib:
        command: |
            wget https://github.com/madler/zlib/archive/v1.2.9.tar.gz
            tar xzvf v1.2.9.tar.gz
            cd zlib-1.2.9
            ./configure
            make
            make install
            ln -fs /usr/local/lib/libz.so.1.2.9 /lib64/libz.so
            ln -fs /usr/local/lib/libz.so.1.2.9 /lib64/libz.so.1
```

Comment: I'm trying manually now. When I run the `make install` command, I'm getting `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig’: Permission denied
make: [install-libs] Error 1 (ignored)
cp libz.a /usr/local/lib
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/usr/local/lib/libz.a’: Permission denied
make: *** [install-libs] Error 1` error

Comment: @AslıKök You have to be root. `sudo su`

Comment: now all the commands work. I will create my `.config` file as you said. Do I need the `sudo su` in my `.config` file?

Comment: @AslıKök You mean your python script works? Yes, you can make it in config file. config files run as root anyway.

Comment: I've created my config file and deployed the application but I got an error in `make`  command.

Comment: `Error encountered during build of prebuild_1_sfm_app: Command 03_make_zlib failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 542, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 260, in build
    changes['commands'] = CommandTool().apply(self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 117, in apply raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)`

Comment: @AslıKök Maybe better if you update your question. I don't know what is your config file.

Comment: @AslıKök Try to add `./configure` as in the updated answer.

Comment: oh yes, you're right. I have added while I was trying manually but I have forgotten to add to the config file. I'm trying again.

Comment: @AslıKök I added `configure` now as well. I also forgot about it originally :-( Not sure if this is the reason why the config file  failed.

Comment: it failed on `./configure` :(

Comment: @AslıKök Have to login to the instance and re-check the commands.

Comment: I've tryed to run these commands manually again and all of them work.

Comment: @AslıKök I will have to try to replicate the config file on my eb instance and check. I don't know for now.

Comment: Okay thank you for your time. If you find anything please share with me :)

Comment: @AslıKök I modified the answer. Had the same issue. New form of the config file works for me. And the reason it was failing was that the `commends` do not "remember" executing `cd zlib-1.2.9`. Co `make` or `configure` were executing in wrong folder.

Comment: Sorry, i couldn't understand what's the difference between your modified answer and my config file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217945/discussion-between-asli-kok-and-marcin).