# I'm unable to install opencv 4.5.4 (C++) on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, ubuntu-20.04

I followed this link (https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-install-opencv-for-visual-studio-code-using-ubuntu-os-9398b2f32d53) to install opencv and I was able to execute it all the way till `make -j4` step. At 99%, I get the following error

```
[ 99%] Built target opencv_annotation
[ 99%] Built target opencv_visualisation
[ 99%] Built target opencv_interactive-calibration
[ 99%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_version
/home/username/miniconda3/envs/ros/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: libz.so.1, needed by ../../lib/libopencv_core.so.4.5.4, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/username/miniconda3/envs/ros/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/bin/ld: ../../lib/libopencv_core.so.4.5.4: undefined reference to `gzeof'
/home/username/miniconda3/envs/ros/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/bin/ld: ../../lib/libopencv_core.so.4.5.4: undefined reference to `gzrewind'
/home/username/miniconda3/envs/ros/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/bin/ld: ../../lib/libopencv_core.so.4.5.4: undefined reference to `gzopen'
/home/username/miniconda3/envs/ros/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/bin/ld: ../../lib/libopencv_core.so.4.5.4: undefined reference to `gzclose'
/home/username/miniconda3/envs/ros/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/bin/ld: ../../lib/libopencv_core.so.4.5.4: undefined reference to `gzgets'
/home/username/miniconda3/envs/ros/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/bin/ld: ../../lib/libopencv_core.so.4.5.4: undefined reference to `gzputs'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [apps/version/CMakeFiles/opencv_version.dir/build.make:87: bin/opencv_version] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3626: apps/version/CMakeFiles/opencv_version.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:163: all] Error 2
```

From what I understand, GCC is unable to find a shared library, *libz.so.1*

So in order to solve this issue I think I have to first locate where the said shared object file is and then let GCC know where to find it to complete the build and I don't know how to do it. (I may be wrong, apologies in advance, I'm a linux noob)

I tried
`ldconfig -v | grep libz.so.1` which returns

```
username@Inspiron-7591:~/opencv/build(master)$ ldconfig -v | grep libz.so.1
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat opt/cubemos/skeleton_tracking/lib: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /usr/local/lib/i686-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /lib/i686-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /usr/lib/i686-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib32' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring

    libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.11
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring

    libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.11
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib32/ld-2.31.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring

/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't create temporary cache file /etc/ld.so.cache~: Permission denied
    libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.11
```

I don't know what the above output is supposed to mean

I've also tried some of the following solutions that I could find but nothing seems to help.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/50097275
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/23454209/15341103
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/22592888/15341103

I even tried giving sudo privileges to the `make -j4` step but no luck

**Note:** I had recently installed ROS in a conda environment named "ros" and gcc is located inside of it.

I've been procrastinating for the past week because of this error and I finally decided to courage up and post it here. **Any** help is **very** much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please avoid posting links on images, instead copy/paste the text here, with adequate formatting. Nobody's gonna click those links.

Comment: Try to run the make command with root user.

Comment: @SaadRami I've already tried running the make command as root but the warning still shows up and I'm unable to complete the build.

Comment: @kebs Apologies, I've removed links to the images.

Comment: you could try to add `-DBUILD_ZLIB=ON` to your cmake cmdline, so it will try to use it's own 3rdparty code instead of your faulty system one

Comment: @berak, Thank you, that helped me solve the issue.