# minimal arch dockerfile to run GUI application

Tags: linux, qt, docker, x11, archlinux

Since arch linux has almost nothing pre-installed, it's not clear how to run a X11 program in a dockerfile. Here's my draft:

```
FROM base/archlinux:latest

RUN pacman-db-upgrade
RUN pacman -Syyu --noconfirm
RUN pacman -S --noconfirm python-pyqt5 python3 qt5-base qt5-quickcontrols2 qt5-multimedia libxcb libx11

WORKDIR /home/project

ENTRYPOINT "/bin/bash"
```

but I'm getting

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the 
Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "".

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What else should I install to make it work?

This is how I'm running the docker container

```
xhost local:root && sudo docker run --rm -it -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -v /home/project:/home/project -e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY name && xhost -
```

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106315/failed-to-load-platform-plugin-xcb-while-launching-qt5-app-on-linux-without