# Error while starting kdevelop in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu-16.04, kdevelop

I am new in linux and i have installed ubuntu 16.04 64 bit on my machine. Installed kdevelop and while launching, I get the following error;

This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin `"xcb"`
in `""`.

Available platform plugins are: `minimal`, `offscreen`, `vnc`, `xcb`, `eglfs`, `linuxfb`, `minimalegl`, `wayland-egl`, `wayland`.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Aborted (core dumped)

Tried debugging as mentioned in ["Failed to load platform plugin "xcb" " while launching qt5 app on linux without qt installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106315/failed-to-load-platform-plugin-xcb-while-launching-qt5-app-on-linux-without)

With `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 /usr/bin/kdevelop`, I get more details but i don't know how to resolve this :

```
Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb")
Cannot load library /usr/lib/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5: symbol _ZTI20QEventDispatcherGlib, version Qt_5_PRIVATE_API not defined in file libQt5Core.so.5 with link time reference)
QLibraryPrivate::loadPlugin failed on "/usr/lib/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so" : "Cannot load library /usr/lib/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5: symbol _ZTI20QEventDispatcherGlib, version Qt_5_PRIVATE_API not defined in file libQt5Core.so.5 with link time reference)"
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"
```

Prior to this, I checked with ldd command and all the dependencies mentioned are available.

```
ldd /usr/lib/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe621d9000)
libQt5XcbQpa.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5 (0x00007fb60f5cc000)
libQt5DBus.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so.5 (0x00007fb60f542000)
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007fb60f224000)
libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007fb60efe1000)
libQt5Gui.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007fb60ea57000)
libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007fb60e4e4000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fb60e2c7000)
```

The list goes on. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: How did you install kdevelop? If you just did `apt-get install kdevelop`, all dependencies should be installed automatically. If you use the AppImage, it should be self-contained.

Comment: I installed it with sudo apt-get install kdevelop first. It gave me the same error. I unintsalled and tried insallation with Synaptic Package Manager. Still the same error

Comment: Synaptic and apt-get do the same thing in the end. As the error message shows a problem with a Qt: Did you do something unusual when installing Qt?

Comment: No, I did not do anything with Qt installation. I faced similar issues whie installing virtualbox on the system. I cleared everything and installed again and it started to work. No luck with Kdevelop though

Comment: Experiencing the same problem in Arch LInux.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue on Arch Linux. Running `kdevelop` from command line revealed the following error messages

> kdevplatform.shell: Can't load plugin "kdevgdb" because a factory to
>   load the plugin could not be obtained: "Cannot load library
>   /usr/lib/qt/plugins/kdevplatform/31/kdevgdb.so: (libokteta2gui.so.2:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)" Connecting
>   to deprecated signal
>
> QDBusConnectionInterface::serviceOwnerChanged(QString,QString,QString)
>   kdevplatform.shell: Can't load plugin "kdevokteta" because a factory
>   to load the plugin could not be obtained: "Cannot load library
>   /usr/lib/qt/plugins/kdevplatform/31/kdevokteta.so:
>   (libkasten3okteta1controllers.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No
>   such file or directory)"

It seems that `kdevgdb` depends on `okteta` which is not installed. I found a corresponding [bug report](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/57119)

Installing `okteta` solved the issue.