# Deploying Qt on Linux

Tags: c++, qt, deployment

I'm trying to deploy a Qt application on different OS.

Windows worked like a charm following [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html) help page. 
Unfortunately, I have problems deploying my software on Linux. 
I have read [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html) help page, but it seems like I'm not understanding the `Plugins` section.

What have I done so far:

- I have compiled my application using QMake
- I have added all dynamically linked libraries (like: `libQt5Core.so.5`, `libQt5Core.so.5.11.2`, `libQt5Gui.so.5`, `libQt5Gui.so.5.11.2`...) to the same directory as my application is (some of them are symlinks for some reason but this is not the issue here)
- I have created a subdirectory called `platforms` and put the `libqxcb.so` library there
- I have created a bash script like suggested in the tutorial which I'm running

**EDIT: the following error is already solved:**

now I struggle how and which plugins I have to put into my directory as well. 
I get the following error message:

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found. 
Available platform plugins are: xcb.
Aborted
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106315/failed-to-load-platform-plugin-xcb-while-launching-qt5-app-on-linux-without) question I did run `ldd libqxcb.so` which lists the following libraries (and many more)

```
./libqxcb.so: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.11' not found (required by ./libqxcb.so)
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd766c5000)
libQt5XcbQpa.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5 (0x00007fd2a6181000)
libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fd2a5f7f000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fd2a5c69000)
libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007fd2a5a24000)
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007fd2a5770000)
libQt5Gui.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007fd2a5007000)
libQt5DBus.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so.5 (0x00007fd2a4d7d000)
libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007fd2a4632000)
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007fd2a43a6000)
...
```

I have seen that the library `libQt5DBus.so.5` is also required. Therefore, I have copied the file (as well as `libQt5DBus.so.5.11.2`) into the parent directory of `platforms` where all my other Qt libraries are.

However, I still get the same error message.

Could it be that it has something to do with the first output of `ldd` since is says "not found"?

```
    ./libqxcb.so: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.11' not found (required by ./libqxcb.so)?
```

When I look at my Windows deployment I have additional folders called `iconengines`, `imageformats`, `styles`, `translations` do I need to provide these folders and libraries as well? If yes where do I find them and how can I check which one I need?

**EDIT: New error**

I figured the first issue out. It was due to a overlooked library namely: `libQt5XcbQpa.so.5`.

However now I get a new error:

```
Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x50602) with this library (version 0x50b02)
```

I noticed that there is an old Qt installation (5.6) on the PC where I want to install the application. I have copied my libraries (5.11) into the same folder as my application is and my bash script calls:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$mydirname
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I thought that this folder is now in the search path for dynamically linked libraries. However, there is this other installation (5.6) as well. Will these libraries be found before or after the libraries in my folder? I'm asking because the 5.6 installation is, for example, missing a QtCharts library, which is provided in my folder, but with version 5.11. May this be the reason for the issue?

Here is a image of my folder:

[image: folder structure]

**FINAL EDIT**

I got it working! The issue was that I have `libQt5DBus.so` instead of `libQt5DBus.so.5`. Therefore it found all libraries in my directory with Version 5.11 except the `libQt5DBus.so` library, which was found in the old installation with version 5.6.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Note that unless you're using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or did something at build time with `rpath`, the Linux loader does not by default look for shared libraries in the current directory.

Comment: good point but I'm using a bash script like recommended in the tutorial, I'll add this information to the question

Comment: for some reason you probably are mixing the system installed version of Qt libraries and the one you installed yourself. You should only use the libraries you are installing (or only those from the system, but that's somewhat more complicated to do).  Using ldd should help you to find the missing libraries.

Comment: Ok this is a good hint. I have noticed that my application depends on `/home/.../Qt/5.11.2/...libQt5Core.so.5` and `libqxcb.so` depends on `/usr/lib/x95_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5`.

Comment: I have adapted the question base on the new findings