# run pyqt5 program, get error: This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in ""

Tags: pyqt5, ubuntu-16.04

I have wirted a program with pyQt5 on ubuntu 16.04, when i run, i get the following error:

This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"
in "".

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Failed to load platform plugin "xcb" " while launching qt5 app on linux without qt installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106315/failed-to-load-platform-plugin-xcb-while-launching-qt5-app-on-linux-without)

Answer (score 0):

I may find the answer. I have install Qt5 and pyQt5 on my ubuntu, there libs may get conflicted. To fix this, I open a new terminal, and reset LD_LIBRARY_PATH without Qt's lib. Then run the program in this terminal. It works well.