# Qt Creator qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: qt, ubuntu, path

I just installed Qt Creator, and then I launch like this:

```
lz@vm:~/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin$ ./qtcreator
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.
```

I tried things like here: ["Failed to load platform plugin "xcb" " while launching qt5 app on linux without qt installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106315/failed-to-load-platform-plugin-xcb-while-launching-qt5-app-on-linux-without) but they assume you're trying to launch your own compiled qt app. I'm trying to launch the qt creator

**UPDATE:**

```
lz@vm:~/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin$ QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 ./qtcreator
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/lz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/lib/Qt/plugins" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/lz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/lz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qbs"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/lz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qbs'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/lz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qbs-config"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/lz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qbs-config'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/lz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qbs-config-ui"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/lz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qbs-config-ui'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/lz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qbs-create-project"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/lz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qbs-create-project'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/lz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qbs-setup-android"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/lz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qbs-setup-android'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/lz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qbs-setup-qt"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/lz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qbs-setup-qt'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/lz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qbs-setup-toolchains"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/lz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qbs-setup-toolchains'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/lz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qt.conf"
QElfParser: '/home/lz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qt.conf' is not an ELF object
"'/home/lz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qt.conf' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/lz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/lz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/lz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator.sh"
QElfParser: '/home/lz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator.sh' is not an ELF object
"'/home/lz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator.sh' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/lz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/lib/Qt/plugins/platforms" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/lz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/lib/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/lz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/lib/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "eglfs"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QEglFSIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("eglfs")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/lz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/lib/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/lz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/lib/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "linuxfb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QLinuxFbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("linuxfb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/lz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/lib/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/lz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/lib/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimal"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QMinimalIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimal")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/lz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/lib/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/lz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/lib/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimalegl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QMinimalEglIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimalegl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/lz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/lib/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/lz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/lib/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "offscreen"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QOffscreenIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("offscreen")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/lz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/lib/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/lz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/lib/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "vnc"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QVncIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("vnc")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/lz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/lib/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/lz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/lib/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "xcb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QXcbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/lz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/platforms" ...
Cannot load library /home/lz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/lib/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (libxcb-xinerama.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
QLibraryPrivate::loadPlugin failed on "/home/lz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/lib/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so" : "Cannot load library /home/lz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/lib/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (libxcb-xinerama.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)"
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: execute `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 qtcreator`

Comment: @eyllanesc look at my update

Comment: execute `sudo apt-get install '^libxcb.*-dev' `